# On which thread does performBlock run?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

Simple question really, my Core Data UIManagedDocument is created on the main thread, what I want to know is when I call performBlock does that block queue/run on the main thread (the same thread where the Managed Document was created)?

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("DownloadQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    // Get data from web
    [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        // Add data to Core Data
    }];
});
```

Comment: ...on a thread other than the main thread =P

Comment: I was under the impression that the managedObjectContext was not thread safe and needed to be accessed on the same thread on which the managedDocument was originally created?

Comment: What NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType are u using?

Comment: I have not directly set that, so I would guess whatever the default is.

Comment: Then you have to set one of the queue-based concurrency types in conjunction with performBlock:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `UIManagedDocument` the managedObjectContext is created (just like it was prior to OS X v10.7 and iOS 5) using what equates to the default Confinement type `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`. Simply put, this concurrency type specifies that the context will not be used on any other thread other than the one that originally created the context.

In this case the `UIManagedDocument` (and its context) were created on the main thread, messaging `performBlock:` will execute the associated block back on the main thread. By using `performBlock:` you don't actually have to know on which thread the managedObjectContext was created, messaging `performBlock:` will always execute its associated block on the same thread the context resides on.

Answer (score 2):

You may read the apple release notes: [CoreData Release Notes for iOS5](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html)

> You can use contexts using the confinement pattern just as you have
>   prior to OS X v10.7 and iOS 5. You send the contexts messages
>   directly; it’s up to you to ensure that you send the messages from the
>   right queue.
>
> You use contexts using the queue-based concurrency types in
>   conjunction with two new methods: performBlock: and
>   performBlockAndWait:. You group “standard” messages to send to the
>   context (including initialization such as setting the persistent store
>   coordinator and so on) within a block to pass to one of these methods.
>   The one exception is: if your code is executing on the main thread,
>   you can invoke methods on the main queue style contexts directly
>   instead of using the block based API.
>
> **performBlock: and performBlockAndWait: ensure the block operations are
>   executed on the queue specified for the context.** The performBlock:
>   method returns immediately and the context executes the block methods
>   on its own thread. With the performBlockAndWait: method, the context
>   still executes the block methods on its own thread, but the method
>   doesn’t return until the block is executed.
>
> It’s important to appreciate that blocks are executed as a distinct
>   body of work. As soon as your block ends, anyone else can enqueue
>   another block, undo changes, reset the context, and so on. Thus blocks
>   may be quite large, and typically end by invoking save:.